# Setting anchor point of sprite to middle

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, rotation, sprite

I am generating sprites programatically like this:

```
this.food = new Sprite();
this.food.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
this.food.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
this.food.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xFF6699, .80, 5, 5, 2, 2, false, false)];
this.food.graphics.endFill();
this.food.x = this.x;
this.food.y = this.y;
this.stage.addChild(this.food);
```

And later on I'm doing this:

```
public function update():void
{
    // Spin the food
    this.food.rotation += 1;
}
```

I basically want the food sprite to spin slowly about its center, not its x and y value which is the top left corner of the sprite.

How can I make the anchor the center of the sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first two parameters of [`drawRect()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawRect%28%29) to offset the graphics:

```
drawRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
```

> Parameters
>
> **`x:Number`** — A number indicating the horizontal position relative to the
>   registration point of the parent display object (in pixels).
>   **`y:Number`** — A number indicating the vertical position relative to the
>   registration point of the parent display object (in pixels).
>   `width:Number` — The width of the rectangle (in pixels).
>   `height:Number` — The height of the rectangle (in pixels).

The idea is to subtract half of the `width` and `height` from the `x` and `y` to centre.

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach using the Matrix Object and the transform method.
Maybe it's still helpful.

http://jamesvango.co.uk/blog/?p=136