# Rotating groups of images in AS3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, rotation, translate-animation

I'm working on a 2d, top-down helicopter game that poses a unique (to me at least) challenge and I'm hoping the stack community can offer some suggestions.  I need the helicopters to be able to rotate, as well as the door guns being able to rotate.  If I put them in a movieclip, then it's not problem and life is beautiful, but I'm putting this together for iOS and movieclips don't play well.  So, I need to use bitmaps.  What are your suggestions for how to track the "mounting points" for the door guns when the helicopter rotates and translate the guns in 2d as well as rotating them?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions (except "google it"- I've done that quite a bit)

Comment: Maybe these [answers] help?
[answers]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917950

Comment: @Matt Comment links are in the format [ text ] ( link ).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a link of a game i made several years ago, its dodgy but its a start has all the source code with it aswell.

http://www.ffiles.com/flash/games/helicopter_game_with_camera_follow_3159.html

also try this as its a top view of a car but the wheels move seperate:

http://ffiles.com/flash/games/flash_racing_game_3161.html

Comment: Thanks for the input guys!  Matt, I can rotate everything on center points with no problem, I more looking for suggestions on how to track the "mounting points" of the guns as the helicopter rotates, or if there is some kind of psudeo-movieclip concept that can be done with bitmaps.  Parele, your game didn't load for me, but I'll try again later.  Thanks again

Comment: it takes half of a minute to load as its 2-3 mb, the website caps the connection at that time i didnt put a loading screen, also to change the rotation move the sprite inside of the parent movieClip this allows easeir transformation point control

Answer (score 0):

just use the MovieClip method that works!

I have at least 200 MCs on the stage at once, and have not had any problems with iPad (iPhone may be a bit more limited, admittedly, but read on!).  As long as you are using instances from the library, and not making a huge number of different icons for the same functionality (e.g., all helicopters should be from the same helicopter), you should be ok.

The main trick is to find and use the memory-saving features of Air.  Movieclips, for instance, should use `cacheAsBitmap` and  [`cacheAsBitmapMatrix`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html).  There are some solutions for the problem of complex MCs that (essentially) dig into the MC and assign `cacheAsBitmap` as needed -- you will have to search for them, though.

Another important tool is object pooling.  This could be the most important concept to implement, if you have a huge number of objects (like bullets).

The point is that if you have a working solution, use it.

In general, though, a trick I use for maintaining a specific point to place things in a MC is to add an 1px X 1px object -- accessible from ActionScript -- and call it `attachPt`.  Then I assign the x,y to a `Point` object called `attachPoint` in the class file, and use that for placement.  At times, I have had to use `globalToLocal()` and `localToGlobal()`.

### Addition:

More tips:

Use matrices for placement and rotation . . . it's finitely faster, and more manageable.

Do not use *any* filters (blur, glow, etc.).  Instead, create PNGs to imitate the effects, if absolutely needed.

Use transparencies in moderation, especially in tweens.

Flatten and combine as many layers as possible.

Again, pooling, pooling, pooling for video games, even with Bitmaps.

Finally, you can always replace MCs with Bitmaps down the line.  Since it is much easier to develop using MCs, you may still want to create the game using them, and swap them out later.  If you know JSFL, you can write a script to make this a trivial task.

Comment: iND, thanks!  I hadn't done any performance testing on the iPad with Movieclips.  On my iPhone 3G it makes for absolute garbage performance (I try to make everything I build run decently on my old phone, then compile with Air 2.6 or above, guarantees to run good on anything newer) even with cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix.  I'll do some tests on the iPad and see how well it works.  Otherwise, it's good ol Algebra/Geometry/Trig to the rescue.

Comment: Ok, if you insist on supporting crappy old tech :).  I added a couple points to my answer, so you may want to look into them.